# Route path with parameters breaks in Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm upgrading an existing Rails 5 application to Rails 7 and am having problems with paths used in link_to().

For example: in my routes.rb I have the following declaration for recording_sets:

```
  resources :recording_sets do
    member do
      get 'export'
    end
    collection do
      get 'about'
    end
  end
```

In Rails 5 I could write add an ad hoc parameter to the path, like so:

```
link_to('Recordings', recording_sets_path(:kind=>1))
```

And in the controller I would pick up this parameter, like so:

```
def index
  if params[:kind]
    @recording_sets = RecordingSet.where('kind = ?', params[:kind]).where(visibility_limitation)
      @kind = params[:kind]
  else
    @recording_sets = RecordingSet.all.where(visibility_limitation)
    @kind = false
  end
    respond_to do |format|
    if @kind.to_s == "1" # Record
      format.html { render action: "index_records" }
    else
      format.html
    end
    format.json { render json: @recording_sets }
  end
end
```

This breaks in Rails 7 with the non-helpful error message:

undefined method `map' for #<ActionDispatch::Journey::Formatter::RouteWithParams... (see the complete long error message at the end)

I have tried to add specifications for the :kind parameter in routes.rb in two different ways:

In the declaration of the resource:

```
resources :recording_sets, param: :kind do
  member do
    get 'export'
  end
  collection do
    get 'about'
  end
end
```

And as a specific path for get:

```
get 'recording_sets/:kind/', to: 'recording_sets#index'
```

And rails routes shows this:

```
GET      /recording_sets/:kind(.:format)    recording_sets#index
```

But the problem remains. What should be done?

The complete error message:

undefined method `map' for #<ActionDispatch::Journey::Formatter::RouteWithParams:0x00000001121e2270 @route=#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Route:0x0000000111d51cb0 @name="recording_sets", @app=#<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::Dispatcher:0x0000000111d52fc0 @raise_on_name_error=true>, @path=#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Path::Pattern:0x0000000111d53060 @ast=#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Ast:0x0000000111d53678 @tree=#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Nodes::Cat:0x0000000111d53998 @left=#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Nodes::Slash:0x0000000111d53d80 @left="/", @memo=#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Route:0x0000000111d51cb0 ...>>, @memo=nil, @right=#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Nodes::Cat:0x0000000111d539e8 @left=#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Nodes::Literal:0x0000000111d53ce0 @left="recording_sets", @memo=#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Route:0x0000000111d51cb0 ...>>, @memo=nil, @right=#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Nodes::Group:0x0000000111d53a88 @left=#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Nodes::Cat:0x0000000111d53ad8 @left=#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Nodes::Dot:0x0000000111d53c40 @left=".", @memo=#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Route:0x0000000111d51cb0 ...>>, @memo=nil, @right=#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Nodes::Symbol:0x0000000111d53ba0 @left=":format", @memo=#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Route:0x0000000111d51cb0 ...>, @regexp=/[^./?]+/, @name="format">>, @memo=nil>>>, @path_params=[:format], @names=["format"], @symbols=[#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Nodes::Symbol:0x0000000111d53ba0 @left=":format", @memo=#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Route:0x0000000111d51cb0 ...>, @regexp=/[^./?]+/, @name="format">], @stars=[], @terminals=[#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Nodes::Slash:0x0000000111d53d80 @left="/", @memo=#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Route:0x0000000111d51cb0 ...>>, #<ActionDispatch::Journey::Nodes::Literal:0x0000000111d53ce0 @left="recording_sets", @memo=#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Route:0x0000000111d51cb0 ...>>, #<ActionDispatch::Journey::Nodes::Dot:0x0000000111d53c40 @left=".", @memo=#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Route:0x0000000111d51cb0 ...>>, #<ActionDispatch::Journey::Nodes::Symbol:0x0000000111d53ba0 @left=":format", @memo=#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Route:0x0000000111d51cb0 ...>, @regexp=/[^./?]+/, @name="format">], @wildcard_options={:controller=>"recording_sets", :action=>"index"}>, @spec=#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Nodes::Cat:0x0000000111d53998 @left=#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Nodes::Slash:0x0000000111d53d80 @left="/", @memo=#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Route:0x0000000111d51cb0 ...>>, @memo=nil, @right=#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Nodes::Cat:0x0000000111d539e8 @left=#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Nodes::Literal:0x0000000111d53ce0 @left="recording_sets", @memo=#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Route:0x0000000111d51cb0 ...>>, @memo=nil, @right=#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Nodes::Group:0x0000000111d53a88 @left=#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Nodes::Cat:0x0000000111d53ad8 @left=#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Nodes::Dot:0x0000000111d53c40 @left=".", @memo=#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Route:0x0000000111d51cb0 ...>>, @memo=nil, @right=#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Nodes::Symbol:0x0000000111d53ba0 @left=":format", @memo=#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Route:0x0000000111d51cb0 ...>, @regexp=/[^./?]+/, @name="format">>, @memo=nil>>>, @requirements={}, @separators="/.?", @anchored=true, @names=["format"], @optional_names=["format"], @required_names=[], @re=nil, @offsets=nil, @requirements_for_missing_keys_check={}>, @request_method_match=[ActionDispatch::Journey::Route::VerbMatchers::GET], @constraints={}, @defaults={:controller=>"recording_sets", :action=>"index"}, @required_defaults=nil, @_required_defaults=[:controller, :action], @required_parts=[], @parts=[:format], @precedence=60, @path_formatter=#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Format:0x0000000111d51a30 @parts=["/", "recording_sets", #<ActionDispatch::Journey::Format:0x0000000111d51b70 @parts=[".", #<struct ActionDispatch::Journey::Format::Parameter name=:format, escaper=#<Proc:0x000000010e1ce580 /Users/christer/Programs/jf7/.gems/gems/actionpack-7.1.3.2/lib/action_dispatch/journey/visitors.rb:8 (lambda)>>], @children=[], @parameters=[1]>], @children=[2], @parameters=[]>, @scope_options={}, @internal=nil, @source_location="config/routes.rb:55", @ast=#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Nodes::Cat:0x0000000111d53998 @left=#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Nodes::Slash:0x0000000111d53d80 @left="/", @memo=#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Route:0x0000000111d51cb0 ...>>, @memo=nil, @right=#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Nodes::Cat:0x0000000111d539e8 @left=#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Nodes::Literal:0x0000000111d53ce0 @left="recording_sets", @memo=#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Route:0x0000000111d51cb0 ...>>, @memo=nil, @right=#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Nodes::Group:0x0000000111d53a88 @left=#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Nodes::Cat:0x0000000111d53ad8 @left=#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Nodes::Dot:0x0000000111d53c40 @left=".", @memo=#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Route:0x0000000111d51cb0 ...>>, @memo=nil, @right=#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Nodes::Symbol:0x0000000111d53ba0 @left=":format", @memo=#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Route:0x0000000111d51cb0 ...>, @regexp=/[^./?]+/, @name="format">>, @memo=nil>>>>, @parameterized_parts={}, @params={:kind=>1}>

```
  super(route_key, options, recall).map(&:dup)
                                   ^^^^
```

Did you mean?  tap

Answer (score 0):

Carefully looking into Gemfile.lock I saw that there were more than one version of some of the Gems, in particular actionpack (which is where the error message came from). I cleaned out all version constraints in Gemfile and rebundled. That fixed this mysterious problem